# Location of the ASP.NET Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7

How/where is the ASP.NET cache managed in IIS 7?  I know that it's stored in the server's memory, but what is the process that manages it?  Is it in the address space of w3wp.exe, or is it in another process/location?  And does Session data use the cache, or does Session work differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configure where Session data gets stored in your `web.config` with the [sessionState element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If set to `InProc`, it will be stored in memory in the `w3wp.exe` process that corresponds to your application's App Pool. You could also, for example, store it in a SQL Server instance.

If that element isn't defined in your config file, check out the machine level `web.config` for your target framework version / architecture.

Comment: You are correct, thanks.  I've done my own digging as well (via Reflector) and come up with more information.  The main ASP.NET Cache object (eventually) implements itself as a managed HashTable.  There's no COM voodoo that I was halfway expecting.  Looks like all of ASP.NET caching is done via managed code, i.e. all cache objects are stored in w3wp.exe's address space.

Comment: To back this up further, I've always thought that recycling the app pool will evict items from `HttpContext.Cache`. I couldn't find any supporting info, but that leads me to believe it's stored in memory in the corresponding instance of `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: Yup, the supporting info is that the cache is stored as a HashTable (check out the System.Web.Caching.CacheSingle class).  No unmanaged code at all.  Now we both know. :)